# Rendering conditionally on an async HTTP request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I have a div which I want to populate with an element of array, which can be either an image or a video. To do this, I am using the Fetch API to parse the header of each element, and get the content-type, and then I want to use that content-type to either render an image or a video.

Here's the problem. I have 2 helper functions, one for images one for videos. This is the way I'd like to do it, but (assuming because of async calls), the helper function gets called and nothing renders. I know for sure the render helper works by the way.

```
checkFileType(url){
  fetch(url, {
  method: "HEAD",
  headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application"
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    var content = res.headers.get("content-type");
    if (content === "image/jpeg"){
        this.renderSIVImage(this.props.item.detail_image_urls[this.state.index]);
    }
    console.log(content);
  }, function(e) {
    alert("Error!");
  });
}
```

So instead I tried using a state variable to keep track, since local variables get scrapped after the fetch. Something like this. And then I check the filetype in the HTML. This **works** but console.logs show me that it is constantly re-rendering which is obviously inefficient.

```
checkFileType(url){
fetch(url, {
  method: "HEAD",
  headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application"
    }
  }).then((res) => {
    var content = res.headers.get("content-type");
    if (content === "image/jpeg"){
     this.setState({
       filetype: "image"
     })
    }
    console.log(content);
  }, function(e) {
    alert("Error!");
  });
}
```

There must be a good solution to this, does anyone have an idea? I'm using React and Django by the way.

EDIT: This is where I call it. the CheckFileType function is essentially just a fetch helper. The URL I'm passing is a link to my local DB, but on production it will be a link to my s3 bucket.

```
<Swipeable
        onSwipedLeft={()=>this.cycleImages("forward")}
        onSwipedRight={()=>this.cycleImages("backward")}
        style={{height:"50%"}}>
        <div>
          {this.checkFileType(this.props.item.detail_image_urls[this.state.index])}
        </div>
</Swipeable>
```

Comment: Could you explicit where this fetch call is done ? In the componentDidMount lifecycle method ?

Comment: I feel like we are missing a part of the puzzle here. Are you calling this in a loop? event?

Comment: @PierreKraemer I am calling it in a carousel I made, and each image/video in the carousel is populated by elements in my DB. It doesn't loop but right now it is checking the file type (correctly) each time I iterate through the items in the carousel. However, it's not rendering unless I replace the checkFileType with a renderSIVImage or renderSIVVideo call (SIV is the name of the component I'm working with)
I don't have a componentDidMount function in this component, would it help here? I need it to update more than once.

Comment: @Jtbs hopefully my edits give enough info? That's all the code that's really relevant I think.

Comment: I think the edit will help someone more familiar with react than I am.

Comment: @PierreKraemer Sorry to spam, but I tried componentDidMount, the problem is that it only runs once. Perhaps I can have it check the entire array but I think it makes more sense to get info and render as needed, if possible

Answer (score 0):

First, if anyone can tell me why it is updating state so many times even though I seemed to call it just once, I am still really curious.

I figured out a workaround for my solution, though. These images/videos are in a rotating carousel, so I `HEAD fetch` once in `componentDidMount` for the initial image, and then I added another `HEAD fetch` in the logic which moves the carousel. That way each carousel movement is associated with exactly one header check.

Comment: You should not call setState in the render method of a component. As setState triggers a re-render of the component, you end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: By the way, you should not call fetch in the render method either. Things could change with the next React Suspense feature, but for now, you should stick on this: render should be a pure function that returns React elements based on the component's props & state. So the approach you ended up with seems to be the good one: side effects (fetch) are done in the methods that handle the events and setState is called when the data is here, which triggers a re-render.